# Could not connect to Ethereum client (testrpc)

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, truffle

I've properly installed geth, truffle and testrpc. Now I'm trying to do some  Ethereum contract tutorials. I initialized project by `truffle init`, so the project folder with default contracts was created, then I ran `testrpc` and compiled contracts by typing `truffle compile` (build directory was created successfully). The thing is, `truffle test` is not working as if there is no testrpc running.I'm using Git Bash on Windows. What might be the problem?
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCUxV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out

1. You need a test file in your directory before you can run `truffle test`
2. You need two CMD window,

   - one to run testrpc command (Do not terminate),
   - second window to compile
     **To compile, run the command below** 

     `Web3 = require('web3')
     web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545")
     solc = require('solc')
     sourceCode = fs.readFileSync('ContractFile.sol').toString()
     compileCode = solc.compile(sourceCode)
     //Get the interface of contract
     contractABI = JSON.parse(compileCode.contracts[':ContractFile'].interface)
     //Get the bytecode of the contract
     bytecode = compiledCode.contracts[':ContractFile'].bytecode
     //Ready to deploy
     ContractFileContract = web3.eth.contract(contractABI)
     //use the object above to deploy the contract
     ContractDeployed = ContractFileContract.new({data: bytecode, from: web3.eth.account[0], gas: 4700000})
     //Check your testrpc console.`
3. Don't forget to declear solidity version at the top of you contract.